# EXTJS 6 Modern: buffered store + grid: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

Here is the fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=1ahm#fiddle/1ahm

Classic theme with nearly the same code works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sencha bug you should report in the official forum in a timely manner.

- `store.getRange()` can be called without start and end parameter. (["The starting index. Defaults to zero."/"The ending index. Defaults to the last record. The end index is included."](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getRange))
- `bufferedStore.getRange()` does not explicitly tell us it can be called without parameters, but we can safely assume it implicitly should, because it is overriding the function definition of the parent class. At least the Modern Grid assumes so.
- `bufferedStore.getRange()` then calls the private function `rangeCached` with `start` and `end` (which are both undefined)
- `rangeCached` obviously expects these two to be numbers, or why else should they even use the strict equality operator at `start === 0 ? 0 : start - 1`?

If it were just this glitch, you could fix it with an override, something like:

```
Ext.define('MyBufferedStoreOverride',{
    override:'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
    getRange:function(start, end, options) {
        if(!Ext.isNumber(start)) start = 0;
        if(!Ext.isNumber(end)) end = this.getCount();
        me.callOverridden([start, end, options]);
    }
})
```

but I think that Sencha never tested their Modern Grid with a `BufferedStore`, because once you got around that first bug, the next error will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the height to the grid and get your grid extend from 'Ext.grid.GridPanel' instead of 'Ext.grid.Grid'.

Comment: You are possibly right, too. After some time I met nearly the same problem on classic theme and setting height to grid worked fine on it. Need to be tested on modern.

Comment: Having no height was the problem in my case!

Answer (score 1):

In **ExtJS 6.6.0** the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.data.BufferedStore.html) for the `bufferedStore` says that for the modern toolkit you must use `Ext.data.virtual.Store`.

Comment: Good find. Oh wow, so much for the "one code, two UIs" approach of Sencha 6. Not even all stores are the same between classic and modern. Just wow.